# GET Parameter not sent Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

This is how I am sending a request

```
// Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_json_obj = "string_req";


    String url =  getResources().getString(R.string.ybase_path)+"strings_u.php";

    String tag_string_req = "req_login";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("a_id", application_id);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/html");

            //headers.put("apiKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            return headers;
        }
    };



                  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest,tag_string_req);
```

and on the server side I am handling the request as

```
if(isset($_GET['a_id']))
```

But it seems the parameters are not sent only. I've been looking for the solution since two days with no luck.

Comment: Whats wrong with this method?

Comment: Sorry you are sending the data to the server use POST method instead of GET in your request.If your are only getting the data from the server then you can use GET method.

Comment: @SagarGangawane it's already has been answer so [don't post answers in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) especially when answer is already there though as a member you can support the answer by upvote if you please , thanks

Comment: @PavneetSingh yup done

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Request.Method.POST` instead of `Request.Method.GET` to send parameters

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
//                                                             ^^^^
```

[For further reading](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

**UPDATE** : you should use `if(isset($_POST['a_id']))` instead of `if(isset($_GET['a_id']))`

Comment: got this error
NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee seems like you are not getting any response , post the complete error with edit in your question

Comment: Sorry seems that error was related to something else. It seems am not getting any response at all. Because OnResponse(String response) is never called

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee make corresponding changes in php code too and post your complete log cat details if error isn't resolved

Comment: posted Logcat pl refer to the question. And yes I did made changes to my php at the begining

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee post the related errors details about this `error NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException:`

Comment: Thanks. Will take over from here

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee you can accept the answer if your problem is resolved and upvote my answer to thanks me